# Move the application to the background on iPhone by PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, html, cordova

I realized that `iOS` is not working on a form that you can close the application.

I work with `PhoneGap` version 2.2.0 and I do like to have my application exit button,

I thought about the possibility to **move the app to the background and back to the iPhone home page** when you click on the button to exit.

I did not find how to do it through `PhoneGap`

is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this post: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17709/can-an-ios-application-have-an-explicit-quit-button

It is quite possible, maybe even likely, that Apple will reject your app for doing this. It should be sufficient for users to close the app simply by pressing the home button.

**UPDATE:** Just because Android has a button for you to close the app does not mean that one is needed on the iOS version. As other posters have said, conventions are different between the two operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a button to exit -- the home button on the device. You do not need to add one in your application.

Comment: Still, this is what I need, how can I run it in the same way that the home button on the device?

Comment: I have this app on Android and it's pretty funny that there will be a button Exit and here not

Comment: @HodayaShalom You can't, it's that simple. And you shouldn't do it in the first place, the user already has a possibility to close your app.

Comment: Android is not iOS. User interface conventions are different between the two operating systems.